# How can i read the 3rd last element from a list with c#?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to write a parser that reads the third to last element from a list. This is a number or nothing. This is my code:

```
public int parseLastId(String filepath)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        String text = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToString();
        lines = text.Split(',').ToList();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(lines[lines.Count - 3]);
        return id;
    }
```

the text in the file is like this:

1,Joe,2,Jeff,

Comment: So the expected output of the example would be "2" ?

Comment: C# 8 introduces [new syntax sugar to indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges). What version are you on?

Comment: _"This is a number or nothing."_ - that's not really representable with int, unless you define some value to represent "nothing" - like for example any negative value. Or you could use `int?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.ReadAllLines` will read every line from a text file.

In your text file, you only have 1 line.

So you can change

```
String text = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToString();
```

to

```
// Get the first line from the text file.
String text = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)[0];
```

The rest of your program is fine then.

### Idiomatic C#

Just to note, that your code isn't written in standard C# style.

In particular:

- `string` should be used instead of `String`.
- Method names should start with a capital letter
- The call to `.ToList()` on `text.Split(',')` is unnecessary.

Here is an edited version of your code that's more in line with typical C# standards - hope that helps :)

```
public int ParseLastId(string filepath)
{
    var text = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)[0];
    var lines = text.Split(',');
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(lines[lines.Length - 3]);
    return id;
}
```

### Error handling

You state that you want to return `nothing` if the program cannot parse the entry. To do that, you will want to return a "nullable int" (`int?`) from your method, and use the [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) method.

For example:

```
public int? ParseLastId(string filepath)
{
    var text = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)[0];
    var lines = text.Split(',');
    
    if (int.TryParse(lines[lines.Length - 3], out var id)
    {
        return id;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upwards from (and including) C# 8 you can also write `lines[^3]`. _"For any number `n`, the index `^n` is the same as `sequence.Length - n`"_ - [What's new in C# 8 - Indices and Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "return nothing" you mean 0

```
public int parseLastId(string filepath)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
    string[] lines = text.Split(',');
    return lines.Length >= 3 && int.TryParse(lines[lines.Length - 3], out int id) ? id : 0;
}
```